# Finding the minimum value of $1/2 (x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2)-x_{2}b_{2}$

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to find the minimum value of the following:

$1/2 (x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2)-x_{2}b_{2}$

I know this is equal to:

$1/2 ([x_1 x_2] Id [x_1 x_2]^T )-[x_1 x_2] [0 b_2]^T$

To find minimum we have to consider the positive definite matrix of $x^T Ax$  When I am calculating the Hessian I get a 2x2 matrix of 0's.

I think I have made a mistake so can anyone help troubleshoot here?

Comment: is $b_2 > 0$? or $ < 0$ ?

Comment: Before calculating any max or min, one should first try to prove it exist.

Comment: @Back2Basic i think it is greater than 0

Answer (score 1):

You do have this as
$$\frac12 \left( x_1^2 + (x_2-b_2)^2-b_2^2 \right)$$

from where the minimum is obvious.